# numpy.unique can't recognise axis argument

Tags: python, numpy, terminal

I'm currently trying to use `numpy.unique` and when I try the [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) on unique rows in 2D arrays,

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 3, 4]])
>>> np.unique(a, axis=0)
```

The following `TypeError` is generated

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unique() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

However, in the documentation I can see that:

> numpy.unique(ar, return_index=False, return_inverse=False,
>   return_counts=False, axis=None)

My numpy version is:

```
# THIS FILE IS GENERATED FROM NUMPY SETUP.PY                             
#                                                                        
# To compare versions robustly, use `numpy.lib.NumpyVersion`             
short_version = '1.15.4'
version = '1.15.4'
full_version = '1.15.4'
git_revision = 'de28edd8f514b82c0524b55f622078d47f479322'
release = True

if not release:
    version = full_version
```

And my python compiler version is:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)
```

The error is generated only in the command line:
All is ok on PyCharm with the same interpreter.

I also confirm in the terminal that I use the above version:

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.15.4'
>>>
```

How can I resolve this issue with my terminal?

Comment: What does `np.__version__` say?

Comment: @Divakar '1.15.4'

Comment: No error here: numpy 1.15.4 on Spyder 3.3.1 Python 3.6.6 -- Output is:  array([[1, 0, 0],[2, 3, 4]])

Comment: No error in PyCharm as well. I call python from the command line. I'll update in the question.

Comment: Sure looks like the commandline version is using an older version of `numpy`.

Comment: @hpaulj I edited the question. Terminal uses the same version of numpy as pycharm

Comment: Our AppVeyor CI pipeline has [begun failing with the same issue under numpy 1.11.3](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/betse/betse/builds/24386030/job/naddirk7lof32n9r). Our Debian-based GitLab CI pipeline, however, [exhibits no such issue](https://gitlab.com/betse/betse/-/jobs/208994024). It is nonsensical. *Moar research is probably warranted.*

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** *Install numpy ≥ 1.13.0.*

### Detail

Due an [AppVeyor CI pipeline spontaneously failing with the same issue under numpy 1.11.3](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/betse/betse/builds/24386030/job/naddirk7lof32n9r), I reluctantly rolled up the dirt-encrusted sleeves <sup>*thanks a lot, bad gardening habit*</sup> and investigated further.

As [every prior commentator suspected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927752/numpy-unique-cant-recognise-axis-argument#comment96620073_54927752), this is a simple versioning issue. In our case, [our multiphysics biology simulator](https://gitlab.com/betse/betse) frequently passes the `axis` keyword argument to the `np.unique()` function and thus implicitly requires numpy ≥ 1.13.0. Naturally, we failed to explicitly declare this requirement in the `install_requires` list of our `setup.py` installer. `</shaking_my_head>`

### Clarifications

We know that [you *think* that your CLI numpy ≥ 1.13.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927752/numpy-unique-cant-recognise-axis-argument#comment96658566_54927752), but this is almost certainly not the case.

Since [numpy ≥ 1.13.0 first introduced the `axis` keyword argument to the `np.unique()` function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.13.0), this argument is guaranteed to also be available under numpy 1.15.4 – the version of numpy you erroneously *think* you've installed within the CLI, but probably haven't. To quote the [official release notes for numpy 1.13.0](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.13.0):

> **axes argument for unique**
>
> In an N-dimensional array, the user can now choose the `axis` along which to look
>   for duplicate N-1-dimensional elements using `numpy.unique`. The original
>   behaviour is recovered if `axis=None` (default).